# What external template works best with knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

On the documentation page [Template Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), Note 5. It says,

> Please note that, as of December 2011, jQuery.tmpl is no longer under active development. In due course, it will be succeded by JsRender, which is currently not yet in beta.

After some googling, I find different alternatives (like `koExternalTemplateEngine`, etc.) and feel hard to decide. I still feel it would be great if the template can be in a separate file. Can any expert here suggest the best solution in this?

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion, using https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine is currently the best option for loading templates from external files.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout has built-in templating, and you can place your templates in files and include them with a script tag on the page. The script type is not important, but I've seen `text/html` used most often.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Comment: Just a note that browsers won't load script tags that have a type other than one of the JavaScript variations, so to load templates from an external file you need to do a bit more work.

Comment: That is the page I was refering to.My concern is in the bottom line of Item 5: Please note that, as of December 2011, jQuery.tmpl is no longer under active development. In due course, it will be succeded by JsRender, which is currently not yet in beta.

If jQuery.tmpl is discontinued?

Comment: jQuery.tmpl is not the same as KnockoutJs's built in template engine. Knockouts template engine has NOT been discontinued. Knockouts template engine is its own entity.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer, I had not heard this before. That's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sample webapi application
    JavaScript bundles:
    "~/Scripts/infuser.js"
    "~/Scripts/koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js"

```
configure:
infuser.defaults.templateUrl = "/templates";
infuser.defaults.templateSuffix = ".tmpl.html";

DEMO:
/Views/Home.cshtml
<!-- ko template:{name:'XXXHolic'} -->
<!-- /ko -->

/Templates/XXXHolic.tmpl.html

<div>
     This is a template.
</div>
```